# WIn10 udate KB3197954 frozen at 45 percent since 15 hours

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, patch

I am currently updating my Windows 10 x64 system, and noticed that the update for KB3197954 is frozen in the Windows update dialog at 45% for several hours now (at least 15 hours). When I look at task manager, I see no more network traffic, but a process called `Windows Modules Installer worker` which takes about 30-35% CPU time of my core-i5 2500k (4 cores).

What is happening here, and why is Microsoft again failing to cleanly and quickly do their update process? Is there any way of knowing if the process is only slow and will finish sometime, or if it has crashed?

Comment: A single windows update would never require more than an hour unless its a big update where it renews the entire OS, such as the anniversary update (or creative update in 2017). If this happens, something likely crashed and you're experiencing a memory overflow. I'd kill the process and reboot, then try again. Chances are it will then install within minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [update KB3197954 from this link](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/crup/2016/10/windows10.0-kb3197954-x64_74819c01705e7a4d0f978cc0fbd7bed6240642b0.msu) from [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3197954). Double click on the MSU and follow the steps to install the update KB3197954.

Comment: Actutally this worked, the question is: why is this necessary at all?

Comment: I have no idea. I sometimes have the same issue and here I also use the MSU. Accept the answer if it worked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235